# Possesive determinant (its)

Tags: possessive-pronouns

What does the possesive determinant (its) refer to in the following sentence , 
The thief returned the painting back to Italy (its) rightful home .
I think (its) refers to Italy .. Any thoughts on that guys ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your teacher is right after all. Try to replace (its) in your sentence (I added the comma):

> Original sentence:
>
> The thief returned the painting back to Italy, (its) rightful home.
>
> Weird sentence:
>
> The thief returned the painting back to Italy, **Italy's** rightful home.
>
> Correct sentence (same meaning as the original):
>
> The thief returned the painting back to Italy, **the painting's** rightful home.

Clearly they mean to say the painting's home is Italy (and not Italy's home is Italy). Therefore, **its** refers back to the painting.